# Send an uploaded image to the server and save it in the server

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I want to upload an image and save it in the server. I uploaded the image an got the preview too, but I am stuck in sending that image to the server. I want to send this image to the server using angular services.

This is the html code

```
<input type="file" fileread="vm.uploadme" />
<img src="{{vm.uploadme}}" width="100" height="50" alt="Image preview...">
```

This is the directive

```
(function(){
    angular.module('appBuilderApp').directive("fileread", [function () {
        return {
            scope: {
                fileread: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: This is my directive to get the image file                                                                                              
app.directive("fileread", [function () {
return { scope: {  fileread: "=" },
 link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
 element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {                                      scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);

Comment: Can you put that in your question please?

Comment: @shamilasallay the BackEnd expects what exactly? Multipart maybe? Let me know so i can give you an aswer.

Comment: Here you will find uploaders for all types of server: http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=file+upload

Comment: @adithya did you try my answer? did it help you? if so please accept my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming in the backend you expect Multipart here is a piece of code that has worked for me.

And here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc1qnw4n/).

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('MyController',

  function MyController($scope, $http) {

    //the image
    $scope.uploadme;

    $scope.uploadImage = function() {
      var fd = new FormData();
      var imgBlob = dataURItoBlob($scope.uploadme);
      fd.append('file', imgBlob);
      $http.post(
          'imageURL',
          fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': undefined
            }
          }
        )
        .success(function(response) {
          console.log('success', response);
        })
        .error(function(response) {
          console.log('error', response);
        });
    }


    //you need this function to convert the dataURI
    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
      var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
      var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
        type: mimeString
      });
    }

  });


//your directive
app.directive("fileread", [
  function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        fileread: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
            });
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="file" fileread="uploadme" />
    <img src="{{uploadme}}" width="100" height="50" alt="Image preview...">
    <br/>
    <p>
      Image dataURI:
      <pre>{{uploadme}}</pre>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="uploadImage()">upload image</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** that the following part:

```
{
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }
}
```

is some Angular magic, in order for $http to parse FormData and find the correct content-type and so on...