# How to make Spring REST service to accept multipart file data sent by the Angular Controller?

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest

I'm trying to post a file from Angular controller to the backend. But Spring REST controller is receiving null.

**JS**

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
             $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                    var formData=new FormData();
                    formData.append("file", $scope.myFile); 
                    alert("Hi");
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'upload', 
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}, 
                        data: formData,
                        transformRequest: function(data, headersGetterFunction) {
                            return data;
                        }
                    }).success(function(data, status) {  
                         console.log('file is ' );
                         console.dir(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status) {
                    });
                }
         }]);
```

**Spring-REST Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
         public @ResponseBody String upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file)  {
                        System.out.println(file);
}
```

I also tried with public @ResponseBody void uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) but it's of no use. I have declared multipartResolver in the configuaration file too. Any Idea on this? I'm desperately looking for a solution.

Comment: So...why is your Content-Type "undefined" instead of, say, "multipart/mixed"?

Comment: @Makoto, By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request.

Comment: @Makoto, It is something wrong with REST itself.

Comment: Why don't you follow this: http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: @RossiRobinsion, I had followed this but I think there is a problem with REST Controller

Comment: @Protagonist did you try my answer? did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that works for me:

**Spring-REST Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users/{id}/image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadUserImage( @PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) {
    return userService.saveUserImage(id, file);
}
```

and on the front-end you could do something like this

**Angular Controller**

```
//the image
$scope.uploadme;

$scope.uploadImage = function() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  var imgBlob = dataURItoBlob($scope.uploadme);
  fd.append('file', imgBlob);
  $http.post(
      '/upload',
      fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      }
    )
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log('success', response);
    })
    .error(function(response) {
      console.log('error', response);
    });
}


//you need this function to convert the dataURI
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
    array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
    type: mimeString
  });
}
```

Assuming that the http request is correct the problem must be at the Spring controller. I think you have to change `upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file)` to  `upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)`. So it will be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)  {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Also in your function you have it return `String` but you are not returning one. So i assume you are doing something else and you removed the code in order to post the question and missed the return, otherwise it wouldn't even build.

Lastly you could [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011326/2442740) that i gave to a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used directive and service and its working. Thanks.